# How to perform GPS coordinates triangulation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, gps, coordinates

I have two GPS coordinates and a distance from each point. I would like to automate the calculation of the two possible GPS coordinates that will match these constraints.

Any ideas on how to start?

Comment: You might have better luck over on https://math.stackexchange.com/.  Note though that the Earth isn't a perfect circle, and there are several standard ways of dealing with this, each with tradeoffs depending on the sort of distances you're looking at.  There are even different coordinate systems optimized for different parts of the world.  Since you're using GPS, you're probably dealing with WGS84.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library to perform advanced geospatial analysis in JavaScript. Triangulation is one the many possibilities.

Here is a code example of a triangulation to find the points that match two constraints of distance.

```js
const center1 = [1.56, 44.58];
const distance1 = 127;
const circle1 = turf.circle(center1, distance1, {
  steps: 1000,
  units: "kilometers"
});

const center2 = [1.89, 44.97];
const distance2 = 89;
const circle2 = turf.circle(center2, distance2, {
  steps: 1000,
  units: "kilometers"
});

const intersections = turf.lineIntersect(circle1, circle2);
console.log(intersections);
// Outputs: [1.49712, 45.72128] and [3.01305, 45.07238]
```

Source: https://tzi.fr/js/triangulation/

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like a reverse haversine function.
We had a working version in the python haversine package : https://github.com/mapado/haversine#inverse-haversine-formula

As Brad suggested, math might help you here. Once you get a formula representing your two circles, you "only" need to find the algorithm that gives you the intersection points (zero, two or infinite)